# How to prevent slashes from being stripped using Regex?

Tags: php, regex

I can't figure out how to change my regex below to keep the slashes. I want to make sure it only contains letters, numbers, underscores, dashes AND slashes.

($query is something like e.g. /offer/some-offer-bla-bla-bla)

```
$query = preg_replace('/[^-a-zA-Z0-9_]/', '', $query);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just include the `/` in the character class. But since you are using `/` as the regex delimiter you need to escape it aswell as `\/`:

```
$query = preg_replace('/[^-a-zA-Z0-9_\/]/', '', $query);
                                     ^^
```

You can make your regex shorter by using `\w` in place of `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, also you can avoid escaping the `/` by using a different delimiter say `~`:

```
$query = preg_replace('~[^-\w/]~', '', $query);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to escape the `/` character but that can make the regex kind of ugly.

You can use a different delimiter like this: (the following is just to show the use of a different delimiter)

```
$query = "hello/world/0123";
echo $query;
$query = preg_replace('{/}', '', $query);
echo $query;
```